# Sending messages to two ActiveMQ brokers using springBoot & camel

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-classic, messagebroker

I'm struggling in creating a Spring Boot application that uses Apache Camel and sends messages to two separate `ActiveMQ` brokers.

I've created two `ActiveMQComponent` beans, each is configured to a different broker. I then defined a router that gets a message from the queue in the first broker, processes it and transfers it to a queue in the second broker.

When I try to run the application I get the following error:

```java
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1: Route(route1)[From[{{primary.input.queue}}] -> [Log[New mess... because of No endpoint could be found for: primary://MyInputQueue
```

My configuration code is:

```java
@Bean("primary") 
public ActiveMQComponent primaryAMQComponent(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, final 
      JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager ) {
    ActiveMQComponent component = new ActiveMQComponent();
    
    component.setBrokerURL("tcp://localhost:61616");
    component.setPreserveMessageQos(true);
    component.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    component.setTransactionManager(jmsTransactionManager);
    return component;
}

@Bean("secondary") 
public ActiveMQComponent primaryAMQComponent(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, final 
     JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager ) {
    ActiveMQComponent component = new ActiveMQComponent();
    
    component.setBrokerURL("tcp://remotehost:61616");
    component.setPreserveMessageQos(true);
    component.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    component.setTransactionManager(jmsTransactionManager);
    return component;
}
```

My router is:

```java
@Component
public class JmsTestRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    
    static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JmsTestRouter.class);

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("{{primary.input.queue}}")
          .log("New message received")
          .process(exchange -> {
              System.out.println("New message received - message text :" + exchange.getMessage().getBody());
              String convertedMessage = exchange.getMessage().getBody() + " is processed ";
              exchange.getMessage().setBody(convertedMessage);
          })
          .to("{{secondary.output.queue}}")
          .log("Message is successfully sent to the output queue")
        .end();
    }
}
```

The properties' definition is:

```
primary.input.queue=primary:MyInputQueue
secondary.output.queue=secondary:MyOutputQueue
```

Apparently I'm doing something wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the configuration code is executed at all? You can debug or add some logging / system out to ensure spring boot calls so there are beans with that name Camel can find.

Comment: Is it normal to have the same `primaryAMQComponent` method in you config for both Beans? For me this code would not compile. But the issue is perhaps somewhere else.